# C++ Can't call a global function?

Tags: c++

So I have a function in app.cpp, and it is defined in the hpp file;

```
class App : public QObject
{
   //Some stuff here

public:
    App();
    void registerToServer(QString apiURL, QUrl params);
```

I am trying to call  the function from another .cpp file. I have done the following in the .hpp file;

```
App m_app;
```

Then my call;

```
m_app.registerToServer(etc etc)
```

However I keep getting an error that App 'does not define a type'

Thanks

Edit: The App.hpp file;

```
#ifndef APP_HPP
#define APP_HPP

#include "service/ConfigurationService.hpp"
#include "service/PushNotificationService.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/GroupDataModel>

#include <bb/system/InvokeManager>
#include <bb/system/SystemCredentialsPrompt>

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/device/HardwareInfo>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>

#include <bps/deviceinfo.h>
#include <bps/netstatus.h>
#include <bps/locale.h>

class PushContentController;

class App : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QString getDevicePIN();
    // The data model that contains all received pushes
    Q_PROPERTY(bb::cascades::GroupDataModel* model READ model CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool modelIsEmpty READ modelIsEmpty NOTIFY modelIsEmptyChanged)

    // The title and body text for the notification dialog
    Q_PROPERTY(QString notificationTitle READ notificationTitle NOTIFY notificationChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString notificationBody READ notificationBody NOTIFY notificationChanged)

    // The title and body text for the activity dialog
    Q_PROPERTY(QString activityDialogTitle READ activityDialogTitle NOTIFY activityDialogChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString activityDialogBody READ activityDialogBody NOTIFY activityDialogChanged)

    // The controller object for the push content page
    Q_PROPERTY(PushContentController* currentPushContent READ currentPushContent CONSTANT)

    // The configuration provider application ID.
    Q_PROPERTY(QString appId READ appId WRITE setAppId NOTIFY appIdChanged)

    // The configuration Push Proxy Gateway(PPG) URL.
    Q_PROPERTY(QString ppgUrl READ ppgUrl WRITE setPpgUrl NOTIFY ppgUrlChanged)

    // The configuration push initiator URL.
    Q_PROPERTY(QString pushInitiatorUrl READ pushInitiatorUrl WRITE setPushInitiatorUrl NOTIFY pushInitiatorUrlChanged)

    // The configuration 'useSdk' value.
    Q_PROPERTY(bool useSdk READ useSdk WRITE setUseSdk NOTIFY useSdkChanged)

    // The configuration 'launchApplicationOnPush' value.
    Q_PROPERTY(bool launchApplicationOnPush READ launchApplicationOnPush WRITE setLaunchApplicationOnPush NOTIFY launchApplicationOnPushChanged)

    // The configuration 'usingPublicPpg' value.
    Q_PROPERTY(bool usePublicPpg READ usePublicPpg WRITE setUsePublicPpg NOTIFY usePublicPpgChanged)
public:
    App();
    void registerToServer(QString apiURL, QUrl params);

    QSettings newConfigSettings;


    /**
     * Saves the Configuration to the persistent store.
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void saveConfiguration();

    /**
     * Loads the Configuration from the persistent store.
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void loadConfiguration();

    /**
     * Returns a value that indicates whether or not the Configuration settings are valid.
     *
     * @return true if valid; false otherwise
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE bool validateConfiguration();

    /**
     * Calls the push service create channel
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void createChannel();

    /**
     * Calls the push service destroy channel
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void destroyChannel();

    Q_INVOKABLE void deletePush(const QVariantMap &item);

    Q_INVOKABLE void deleteAllPushes();

    Q_INVOKABLE void markAllPushesAsRead();
    Q_INVOKABLE void changeConnectionText(const QString newText);
    /**
     * Marks the passed push as current one and prepares the controller
     * object of the PushContentPage.
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE void selectPush(const QVariantList &indexPath);
    Q_INVOKABLE void sendSms(const QString &messageText, const QStringList &phoneNumbers);
public Q_SLOTS:
    void onCreateSessionCompleted(const bb::network::PushStatus &status);
    void onCreateChannelCompleted(const bb::network::PushStatus &status, const QString &token);
    void onDestroyChannelCompleted(const bb::network::PushStatus &status);
    void onRegisterToLaunchCompleted(const bb::network::PushStatus &status);
    void onUnregisterFromLaunchCompleted(const bb::network::PushStatus &status);
    void onRegisterPromptFinished(bb::system::SystemUiResult::Type value);
    void onUnregisterPromptFinished(bb::system::SystemUiResult::Type value);
    void onPIRegistrationCompleted(int code, const QString &description);
    void onPIDeregistrationCompleted(int code, const QString &description);
    void onInvoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest &request);
    void onSimChanged();
    void onPushTransportReady(bb::network::PushCommand::Type command);
    void quit();

private Q_SLOTS:

    void httpFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);


Q_SIGNALS:
    void modelIsEmptyChanged();
    void notificationChanged();
    void activityDialogChanged();

    void appIdChanged();
    void ppgUrlChanged();
    void pushInitiatorUrlChanged();
    void useSdkChanged();
    void launchApplicationOnPushChanged();
    void usePublicPpgChanged();

    void openActivityDialog();
    void closeActivityDialog();

private:

    PushDAO m_pushDAO;

    // A helper function to initialize the push session
    void initializePushSession();
    bool validateUser(const QString &dialogTitle, const QString &username, const QString &password);
    void loadUser();
    void setPromptDefaultText(bb::system::SystemCredentialsPrompt* prompt,const QString &username, const QString &password);
    void pushNotificationHandler(bb::network::PushPayload &pushPayload);
    void showDialog(const QString &title, const QString &message);
    void openActivityDialog(const QString &title, const QString &message);

    void onNetworkStatusUpdated ( bool connectionStatus, QString interfaceType );
    // The accessor methods of the properties
    bb::cascades::GroupDataModel* model() const;
    bool modelIsEmpty() const;

    QString notificationTitle() const;
    QString notificationBody() const;
    QString activityDialogTitle() const;
    QString activityDialogBody() const;

    PushContentController* currentPushContent() const;

    QString appId() const;
    void setAppId(const QString &appId);
    QString ppgUrl() const;
    void setPpgUrl(const QString &ppgUrl);
    QString pushInitiatorUrl() const;
    void setPushInitiatorUrl(const QString &pushInitiatorUrl);
    bool useSdk() const;
    void setUseSdk(bool value);
    bool launchApplicationOnPush() const;
    void setLaunchApplicationOnPush(bool launchAppOnPush);
    bool usePublicPpg() const;
    void setUsePublicPpg(bool usingPublicPpg);

    QString getDeviceIMEI();


    // The manager object to react to invocations
    bb::system::InvokeManager *m_invokeManager;

    // The credentials dialog to register to the push service
    bb::system::SystemCredentialsPrompt *m_registerPrompt;

    // The credentials dialog to unregister from the push service
    bb::system::SystemCredentialsPrompt *m_unregisterPrompt;

    // The wrapper classes for loading/storing configuration values
    ConfigurationService m_configurationService;
    Configuration m_configuration;

    // The wrapper class for the current user
    User m_user;

    PushNotificationService m_pushNotificationService;

    bool m_shouldRegisterToLaunch;
    bool m_shouldUnregisterFromLaunch;

    // The controller object for the push content page
    PushContentController* m_pushContentController;

    // The property values
    bb::cascades::GroupDataModel *m_model;
    QString m_notificationTitle;
    QString m_notificationBody;
    QString m_activityDialogTitle;
    QString m_activityDialogBody;
    QString m_appId;
    QString m_ppgUrl;
    QString m_pushInitiatorUrl;
    QString m_connectionStatus;
    bool m_useSdk;
    bool m_launchApplicationOnPush;
    bool m_usePublicPpg;

    QString device_pin;


    QNetworkAccessManager m_accessManager;
    UserDAO m_userDAO;
    QNetworkReply *m_reply;

    ConfigurationDAO m_testConfig;
};

#endif
```

RegisterToServer function.

```
    void App::registerToServer(QString apiURL, QUrl params)
{
    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl(apiURL);
    QByteArray postData;
    postData = params.encodedQuery();

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl),postData);

    // Connect to the reply finished signal.
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(httpFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include "my_hpp_file.hpp"`?   Please show enough code that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: could be a missing ; after the closing } from your class definition

Comment: Yes, included the file. And yes I have missed off a closing brace in my post, me just being lazy! In my code, the class is properly defined. It's hard to post the whole code as I'm building an App for BlackBerry 10.

Comment: If your code was completely proper, you wouldn't be having a problem now, would you?  Show your code  (Not your *complete code*.  But enough code to show the problem)

Comment: This is a typical case of "the problem isn't in the code you have posted, but the bit(s) you have not posted..."

Comment: OK, changed with my code.

Comment: Problem code still hasn't been posted. Obviously the problem is on the line where the compiler error is **and** all the code leading up to that point.

Comment: Show the code where the function is being called from.

Comment: And the line to which the error applies (which hasn't been made clear).

Comment: You wrote "I have done the following in the .hpp file: `App m_app;`"
Then you posted your .hpp file, and I don't see that line in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think (not 100% sure), there is already a file, which defines APP_HPP.

For instance I found this googling:
https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/blob/master/invoketarget/src/app.hpp

But I am not a BB expert. :-)

Change your include guard.

Comment: You know, you could be a genius

Comment: Believe me: I am not. :-)

Comment: One can confirm this by adding an intentional error in the `app.hpp` file. E.g. `#error This should be an error if all works`